# XPath for an element with only child elements named X?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Let's say I have this example:

```
<div>
<p>some text <em>emphasized text</em> some other text</p>
<p><em>The paragraph I want to capture</em></p>
<p>some text <em>emphasized text</em> some other text and <em>other em text</em> until the end.</p>
</div>
```

What I want to select is the second paragraph (but it may be third or first as well). The thing is that here `p` and `em` are adjacent. There is no text between `<p>` and `<em>`, not at the beginning nor in the end. All text is inside `<em>xyz</em>`.

How can I get it with XPath query ?

I tried `//p/em`, /`/p/child:em`, `//em/parent:p`, all these select the three paragraphs as all `em` are children of `p`.
`//p[starts-with(.,'./em')]` didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Per the comments, OP clarifies:

> Yes, I want to capture any paragraph that contains only emphasized text, is it enclosed in one or more `em` tags.

Therefore, I suggest this updated XPath,

```
//p[em][not(node()[not(self::em)])]
```

will select all `p` elements with one or more `em` child elements, but no other children of any sort — only fully emphasized paragraphs.

---

## Old answer

This XPath,

```
//p[count(node())=1][em]
```

will select all `p` elements with a single child node that is a `em` element.

### Explanation

- `//p` selects all `p` elements in the document.
- `[count(node())=1]` filters to only those `p` elements that have a single child `node()`.  Since `node()` matches nodes of *any* type (including both element nodes and text nodes), it will ensure that only `p` elements with a single child of any type are selected.
- `[em]` filters to only those single-child `p` elements that have a `em` element child.

Therefore, for your input XML/HTML, only the targeted `p`,

```
<p><em>The paragraph I want to capture</em></p>
```

will be selected. Had there been another `p` with three `em` children,

```
<p><em>Do</em><em>not</em><em>select</em></p>
```

or one `em` child and other element children,

```
<p><em>Do</em><sup>not</sup><sub>select!</sub><span> or else!</span></p>
```

such `p` elements would *not* have been selected.

**Warning**: The XPath in the other answer here, `//p[not(text())][em]`, however, would select such `p` elements.

## See also

- [XPath for element whose children start and end with element X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78053930/290085)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Xpath, which will select the paragraph with only `em` and no direct text.

`//p[not(text())][em]`

[image]

Comment: Thank you supputuri. That's it. I had try //p[(text()='')][em] but it didn't work. I haven't thought about **not**(text())

Comment: This would also select `<p><em>one</em><em>two</em></p>`.   @user15739925: Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I want to capture any paragraph that contains only emphasized text, is it enclosed in one or more `en` tags.

Comment: Ok, but realize that this XPath would also select `<p><em>Do not</em><span class="notEmpasized">select me.</span></p>`.