# XPath for element whose children start and end with element X?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath

Here is my example:

```
<div>
  <p><em>Emphasized text</em> followed by any <span>other text</span> and ending with an <em>emphasized text</em></p>
</div>
```

What I wan is to catch this paragraph which starts with `em` and ends with `em`. Between these tags may be text including other inline tags like `span`, `img`, `a`, etc.

A real world example can be some academic and newspaper writing rules when you have to emphasize a text inside an already emphasized text then you cancel the emphasis which is inside the emphasis, i.e. author presentation or bibliography:

If we have this phrase: -- John Doe is the writer of "Emphasis inside emphasis" book. -- One printing rule is to write it like this:

John Doe is the writer of *Emphasis inside emphasis* book.

But when you have to print this paragraph emphasized, it will become:

*John Doe is the writer of* Emphasis inside emphasis *book.*

Same thing with bibliography presentation:

John Doe, *Emphasis inside emphasis*, NY, Publisher Name, 2024.

Which emphasized becomes:

*John Doe,* Emphasis inside emphasis, *NY, Publisher Name, 2024.*

Consider that some of this text (author's, name, publisher's name or book's name) may be anchored to a link.

This question is an extension of [a previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78051058/xpath-for-an-element-with-only-child-elements-named-x) where we were seeking for just a `p` started and ended by an `em`. Some answers were provided covering simple or more complex cases dealing with `p` followed by one or more `em` and no other text between the tags. The difference here is that we have some text between the tags but the main purpose is the same: the paragraph starts and ends emphasized whatever may be in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[node()[1][self::em]][node()[last()][self::em]]
```

will select all `p` elements whose children start with and end with `em` elements, as requested

Comment: You rock, man! It works great and adding `[1]` I can select the first occurrence as the paragraph I wan to capture is always on top of the text. Thank you.